# Is there a connection between the "independent sets" in matroids and "independent sets" in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, matroids

I've been reading up on [matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) recently, which are used in the theory of greedy algorithms. A matroid is a pair $(X, I)$ where $X$ is a set and $I \subseteq \wp(X)$ is a family of sets over $X$ called the *independent sets* in $X$.

It occurred to me that I'd seen the term "independent set" also used in a [graph-theoretic context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) to refer to a set of nodes in a graph where no two nodes in the set are adjacent.

I'm not immediately seeing a connection between these two kinds of independent sets. Notably, in a matroid, all maximal independent sets are required to have the same cardinality, while in a graph theory context, it's possible for there to be many different maximal independent sets of differing cardinalities.

Is there a connection between these two concepts of "independent sets," or is the terminology just an accident of history?

Comment: I believe it's a coincidence of notions, but I wonder if any relation exists.

Comment: The independent sets of matroids generalize sets of linearly independent vectors in a vector space.

Comment: @templatetypedef: You can define an *independence system* (which is weaker than a matroid) on the independent vertices of a graph $G = (V(G), E(G)$: choose $V(G)$ as ground set and the set of independent subsets of vertices of $G$ plus the empty set as the *independent sets* of the independence system. You are right, of course, that in a graph theory context, it's possible for there to be many different maximal independent sets of differing cardinalities.To remedy this check (e.g.) vertex-transitive graphs or other graph-types with a very high form of symmetry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on @Moritz's comment, it seems like the answer comes from a related mathematical structure called an [independence system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_system), which is a pair $(X, I)$ where $X$ is a ground set, $I \subseteq \wp(A)$, and $I$ obeys the following properties:

- $I \ne \emptyset$, and
- $\forall S \in I. \wp(S) \subseteq I$.

The sets in $I$ are called *independent sets*. The set of all independent sets in a graph $G$ form an independence system, since there's always at least one independent set (namely, the empty set) and any subset of an independent set is also an independent set.

A matroid is an independence structure that also satisfies the exchange property, which is something that independent sets in a graph-theoretic sense do not obey. So in that sense, the connection between independent sets in graph theory and independent sets in matroids comes from the independence structure of a matroid, not the exchange property.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that arguably the clearest example of graphs for which the set of independent sets do not constitute a matroid are *complete $r$-partite graphs* There, each partition class is inclusion-maximally independent, and these classes can be made as unequally-sized as one wishes. Moreover, the exchange-axiom then obviously does *not* hold, proving that in this graph the independence complex is not a matroid.